# Android not toasting in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I have a BroadcastReceiver that is supposed to make a toast when a download has finished, as follows:

```
class DownloadBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE == intent.action) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.toast_save_successful, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("DownloadBroadcastReceir", "toasted")
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the debug message in the logs but the toast does not appear.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

**For context**, here is the call to the downloader service:

```
val downloader = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
downloader.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(destinationLocation)
        .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
        .setTitle(filename)
        .setDescription(resources.getString(R.string.downloader_description, sourceFilename))

(saverActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager).enqueue(downloader)
```

Here it is registered in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.DownloadBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The application has usually closed by the time the download has finished. Does that make a difference?